# Different way to write besides switch statement

Tags: javascript

I have the following switch statement:

```
        switch (result.innerHTML) {
            case "":
            case "&nbsp;":
                result.innerHTML = "Stage1";
                result.style.backgroundColor = "green";
                break;
            case "Stage1":
                result.innerHTML = "Stage2";
                result.style.backgroundColor = "red";
                break;
            case "Stage2":
                result.innerHTML = "Stage3";
                result.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
                break;
            case "Stage3":
                result.innerHTML = "Stage4";
                result.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
                break;
            case "Stage4": //start over
                result.innerHTML = "";
                result.style.backgroundColor = "";
                break;
            default:
        }
```

Is there another concise way of doing this in JavaScript? Maybe using arrays or JavaScript objects?

Comment: It depends on what you think is 'cleaner'. A state machine would be cleaner, but it would be quite a lot more code.

Comment: Yes, you could use an object. The keys would be `""`, `"&nbsp;"`, etc.

Comment: An object would work fine, but I don't think there is an issue with the switch statement based on efficiency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the switch. It's easy to read and understand. Sometimes shorter code isn't always better code.

Here's an alternative.

```
var states  {
    "":         ["Stage1","green"],
    "&nbsp;":   ["Stage1","green"],
    "Stage1":   ["Stage2","red"],
    "Stage2":   ["Stage3","yellow"],
    "Stage3":   ["Stage4","pink"],
    "Stage4":   ["",""]
};
if(result.innerHTML in stages)
{
    result.style.backgroundColor = stages[result.innerHTML][1];
    result.innerHTML = stages[result.innerHTML][0];
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my OP. I like switch also. I just wanted to get another perspective.

Comment: I like if-else statements, where you get the same functionality and forgetting "break" gives you less critical bugs. I agree about shorter code, but shorter code usually means better readability and less place for errors / typos.

Comment: I'd use a dictionary instead of a list to make it slightly more self documenting: `result.style.backgroundColor = stages[result.innerHTML].backgroundColor`

Comment: @StevenBurnap same thing, except writing the code to define `backgroundColor` as an object property is a lot more typing.

Answer (score 3):

You should put the background colors in CSS with different classes (`stage1`, `stage2`, etc.) and store the current stage as a separate variable.

```
var currentStage = 0;

function proceed() {
    currentStage = (currentStage + 1) % 5;
    result.innerHTML = currentStage === 0 ? '' : 'Stage' + currentStage;
    result.className = 'stage' + currentStage;
}
```

It'll make for much cleaner code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There is (if,else if and else) statements but switch statement is alot cleaner than them.